# How do I convert AddComponentInstance to Register

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

The AddComponentInstance of:

```
WindsorContainer.Kernel.AddComponentInstance<T>(typeof(T), instance);
```

is obsolete.

It's replacement is:

```
WindsorContainer.Register(Component.For<IClassParameters>().ImplementedBy<ClassParameters>());
```

However I have a facade:

```
public static void AddInstance<T>(object instance)
    {
        _iocManager.WindsorContainer.Kernel.AddComponentInstance<T>(typeof(T), instance);
    }
```

I can't see how to use the Register method instead of AddComponentInstance.
This is wrong:

```
_iocManager.WindsorContainer.Register(Component.For<T>().ImplementedBy<T>().Instance(instance));
```

What should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

```
        public static void AddInstance<T>(T instance) where T : class 
    {
        _iocManager.WindsorContainer.Register(Component.For<T>().Instance(instance));
    }
```

Note the method signature forcing the compiler to take T as a Class and hence as a Ref variable

Answer (score -1):

```
container.Register(Component.For<Foo>().Instance(new Foo());
```

Comment: No ,that doesn't work. I substituted <FOO> with T and FOO with instance and got errors